# NULL value of data while fetching it from firbase in next js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have my nextjs app in which i have implemented stripe for payment and firebase for database .The users data is stored in firebase with all the required values but while fetching it to display on the orders page it gives an empty array. The query to fetch the data is successful but data array is null.

MY ORDERS PAGE

```
import Navbar from "@/Components/Navbar";
import React from "react";
import { useSession, getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { moment } from "moment";
import db from "../../firebase";
import Orderr from "@/Components/Orderr";

function Orders({ orders }) {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log(orders);
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <main className="max-w-screen-lg mx-auto p-10">
        <h1 className="border-b mb-2 pb-1 ">Your Orders</h1>
        {session ? (
          <h2>{orders ? orders.length : 0} orders</h2>
        ) : (
          <h2>Please sign in to see your orders</h2>
        )}
        <div>
          {orders?.map(({ id, amount, items, timestamp, images }) => (
            <Orderr
              key={id}
              id={id}
              amount={amount}
              items={items}
              timestamp={timestamp}
              images={images}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Orders;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
  const session = await getSession(context);
  if (!session) {
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }
  // firbase db
  const stripeOrders = await db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(session.user.email)
    .collection("orders")
    .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    .get();

  console.log(stripeOrders);
  const orders = await Promise.all(
    stripeOrders.docs.map(async (order) => ({
      id: order.id,
      amount: order.data().amount,
      images: order.data().images,
      timestamp: moment(order.data().timestamp.toDate()).unix(),
      items: (
        await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(order.id, {
          limit: 100,
        })
      ).data,
    }))
  );

  console.log(orders);
  return {
    props: {
      orders,
    },
  };
}
```

Firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBpb1-3U22I3ajHcTFoUnwIAajzRu64KNo",
  authDomain: "meraki-corner.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "meraki-corner",
  storageBucket: "meraki-corner.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "384440845152",
  appId: "1:384440845152:web:92ce7ab8428ac30c029405",
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
export default db;
```

Answer (score 0):

**use a const session: any = await getSession();**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).